# will the gas to execute my function increase if the array of object get bigger in the future?

Tags: solidity, gas

From the contract below, if the `logs` get bigger and bigger (let's say it contains 1M items).

The cost for calling `set` will be increase or not?

I think that the cost for calling when the array size is 10 and 1M should be the same because the operation in `set` function is not different.

But I am not sure, so that I post this question.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Storage {
    struct Log {
        string fname;
        string lname;
        string dob;
    }
    mapping (uint => Log) logs;

    function set(uint memory index, string memory fname, string memory lname, string memory dob) public returns (uint) {
        index++;
        logs[index] = Log(fname, lname, dob);
        return (index);
    }

    function get(uint idx) public view returns (string memory, string memory, string memory) {
        return (logs[idx].fname, logs[idx].lname, logs[idx].dob);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no array here BTW.

Comment: @goodvibration sorry it is `mapping`, not `array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it should will the same regardless of how many items you already have stored in your mapping. Gas costs will only vary depending on the lengths of the `strings` you're storing.

Comment: thanks, i think that it will look like this also, but asking to make sure